# Is it a considered a recursive function if I have an overloaded function that calls one of its other instances?

Tags: c++, class, recursion, constructor, function-calls

This is hypothetical, but I have a class with two, overloaded constructors - none of which are the default constructors.  If I were to call one constructor from the other, would it be recursive? Example:

```
class Example
{
     Example(const int integer)
     {
          //Constructor Code Here
     }

     Example(argument)
     {
          Example object(68);
          //Rest of constructor code
     }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Easier to answer if you posted some code.

Comment: A function/method is recursive if it calls itself... it sounds like in your example, the copy constructor calls the other constructor, but no constructor calls itself.  So from your description, the answer would seem to be no.

Comment: @jeremy Well, there could be levels of indirection.

Comment: Yes, I thought about including that, but I thought it would only serve to confuse the issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

Recursion is when a function calls *itself*, not an overloaded function of the same name with different parameters.  What you are describing is not recursion at all. It is [**delegating constructors**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor), a new feature introduced in C++11.  And by definition: "Delegating constructors cannot be recursive".